# Executing Stored Procedure Error Message for data type

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure that I created to add a new flight. The code for the stored procedure executed successfully, however when I try to execute it I get an error message

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure Addnewflight, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Error converting data type varchar to time

This is my stored  procedure statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Addnewflight 
     @f_id INT, 
     @dep_city VARCHAR(50), 
     @dest_city VARCHAR(50), 
     @no NUMERIC(12, 2),
     @dt DATETIME,
     @total_passenger NUMERIC(12, 2), 
     @r_id INT, 
     @dep_time TIME(7)
AS
    DECLARE @count INT;
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.flight WHERE flight_id = @f_id)

    IF @count = 0 AND @dep_city <> @dest_city 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.[flight] ([flight_id], [departure city], [destination city], [number], [date], [total number of passengers], [reservation_id], [departure time]) 
        VALUES (@f_id, @dep_city, @dest_city, @no, @dt, @total_passenger, @r_id, @dep_time)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Duplicates are not allowed. Destination and departure city cannot be the same.';
END
```

Here is my table query script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[flight]
(
    [Flight_ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Departure City] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Destination City] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Number] [NUMERIC](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [DATE] NOT NULL,
    [Total Number of Passengers] [NUMERIC](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Reservation_ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Departure Time] [TIME](7) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_flight] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

This is how I execute this stored procedure:

```
EXEC Addnewflight 27, Baltimore, Miami, 302, '20110412', 240, 709, '12T:06:07.00'
GO
```

Comment: Remove the `T` from your input `'12T:06:07.00'`. It will work.

Comment: I removed the T and now I received another error message:
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure Addnewflight, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_flight_reservations". The conflict occurred in database "db17", table "dbo.reservations", column 'Reservation_ID'.

I am not sure if its because I made the foreign key Null, so I can't add a value to it.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: That is foreign key violation error, which means you are trying to insert a value  which is not in the master table. Please check the data.

Comment: Please check the value `709`, exists in your `dbo.reservations` table.

Comment: Yes, we can insert the foreign key referenced column values, only if they exists in the primary key column.

Comment: The cities need to be in **single quotes** in your `EXEC` statement .. - `EXEC Addnewflight 27, 'Baltimore', 'Miami', 302, .... `

Comment: How do I insert a value into the primary key table to show on the foreign key without getting an error message?

Comment: Please check this link for solution of foreign key issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330353

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the mal-formed time literal passed as the `@dept_time` value. Specify an ISO 8601 time literal like below and also enclose string literals in single quotes:

```
EXEC Addnewflight 27, 'Baltimore', 'Miami', 302, '20110412', 240, 709, '12:06:07.00';
```